# How to translate a 'where' mySQL query to method syntax?

Tags: java, android, sql

I want to write a mySQL read query:

```
    String query = "SELECT  * FROM " + MY_TABLE
            + "where phone=" + phone + "AND isBloacked =1";
```

how can I transform this to method syntax?

```
    Cursor cursor = getReadableDatabase().query(MY_TABLE,
            new String[] { "phone" }, "phone", new String[] {}, null, null,
            null);
```

Comment: Try this: `Cursor cursor = getReadableDatabase().rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + MY_TABLE + " WHERE phone = ? AND isBloacked = 1", new String[]{phone});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your 3rd parameter is basically a `WHERE` clause, just without the word `WHERE`.

```
public Cursor query (String table, String[] columns, 
    String selection, String[] selectionArgs, 
    String groupBy, String having, String orderBy, String limit)
```

From the method signature the `selection` is the `WHERE` clause, and `selectionArgs` allows you to add parameters outside of the string.

For example, for your query you may want to do something like:

```
Cursor cursor = getReadableDatabase().query(MY_TABLE,
        new String[] { "phone" }, 
        "phone = ? AND isBloacked = ?", new String[] { phone, "1" }, 
        null, null, null);
```

Comment: And, in case you need a more complex query, you can always use the `rawQuery()` method.

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient and probably the most convenient way for you is to use `.rawQuery`, which also returns a `Cursor`, just as simple `.query`. I assume it's good since you obviously know what to write in it, and it works a tiny bit faster. Here it goes:

```
Cursor cursor = getReadableDatabase().rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + MY_TABLE
    + " WHERE phone = " + phone + " AND isBloacked = 1", new String[]{phone});
```

Comment: This one is much better: `Cursor cursor = getReadableDatabase().rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + MY_TABLE
        + " WHERE phone = ? AND isBloacked = 1", new String[]{phone});`